# Convert Javascript data to image source

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have the following code:

```
function myFunction(title) {
        var searc_url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cc47980e&t='.concat(title)
        $.getJSON(searc_url,
        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data["Title"])
            console.log(data["Year"])
            console.log(data["imdbRating"])
            console.log(data["Poster"])
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data["Title"]
            document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = data["Year"]
            document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML = data["imdbRating"]
            document.getElementById("myImg").src = data["Poster"]
        }
        )
        }
```

I am trying to call an image from an API, where I call:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = data["Poster"]
```

(The API returns the website url of the image).

Then, when I try to link this as an image in my body like so:

```
<img id="myImg" src='data["Poster"]' alt="The Pulpit Rock">
```

The image never loads. I just get the alt text. I've tried doing this, and I've tried

```
<img src="myImg" alt="Movie Image">
```

but this behaves similarly.

I've tried to google this but I'm pretty new to Javascript, HTML and PHP as a whole so it's hard to sift through the technical jargon.

Do I need to be converting this to a variable in some way that I am not??

I am just having issues displaying it on the page- not sourcing it from the API.
The  is not properly getting the variable I have set (id = myImg) that contains the url.

Thanks!

EDIT: Oops. Turns out this code does work- the issue was that my browser was blocking the scripts! Oops!

Thanks everyone.

I was trying to figure out why this wasn't cooperating.

Comment: What is displayed in the console for `console.log(data["Poster"])`? Also, why are there no `;` in your code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("myImg").src = data["Poster"]` is the only method that could possibly work ... but .. what does `console.log(data["Poster"]) actually output?

Comment: @Jaromanda The log returns "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: @Tigger This is mostly HTML code- so no semi-colons.

Comment: Oh, you'd need `<img id="myImg">` somewhere

Comment: right, so what title are you passing in the function? https://jsfiddle.net/xcb02egy/ your code works (but not for the title "The Pulpit Rock")

Comment: @JaromandaX Oops! Resolved. My browser was blocking script execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you save the value in another variable, like charge it.

```
var imgValue = data.poster;
```

and lather set that value to img attribute;

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = imgValue.toString();
```

I hope it can help you, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ooops! Resolved!

My browser was blocking my scripts.

The method above does, indeed work. Sourcing with id="myImg"